# Is the linear regression adequate to analysis my data?

Tags: regression, modeling, linear, epidemiology

I have a set of patients who have medical issues, and a medical staff who try to resolve this issues. each patient has many issues and can visit the medical staff one or many times, at each visit, issues can be resolved or not or discovered. I want to prove that the medical staff decreases the number of medical issues or at least prove that there are a linear association between the diminution of medical issues and the intervention of the medical staff, also I want to take into account some co-variable. Which method will be the more adequate for my data? linear regression? Should/can I take the number of visit as a co-variable?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your intended model. It sounds like your dependent variable is number of medical issues. Your independent variables aren't clear to me-- how are you defining "intervention of the medical staff"?

Comment: It looks like your "medical staff" is a secondary physician, because "medical issues" are usually established by a referring physician. Not many patients would walk up to me off the the street and say, "Doctor, I have tachycardia, night sweats, insomnia, heat intolerance, heat rashes, hair loss, tremor, hyperphagia, exophthalmos and recent onset goitre. Therefore, I have hyperthyroidism, please cure me." That brings up lots of issues, what classification of "issues" are you using? Is the list 10 issues, or one, Graves disease? What about the hypothyroidism I will cause when I cure it?

Comment: What I am trying to do is pry some details out of you about what your data is, how it is classified, how secondary issues such as those resulting from therapy, and how additional diagnoses and conditions identified by your medical staff are treated in your data. For example, stomach ache can convert into stomach cancer after a visit to your medical staff, and the question is, how do you treat that problem wise. Is that a medical issue that is solved?

Comment: @Carl other issues can be resolved or not or discovered, through the time (visits).

Comment: I vote to close given the poor framing of the question, deprived of specifics. I find it concerning that this question reflects clinical care somewhere. What are "issues"? Diagnoses? All diagnoses treated the same way? Just number of diagnoses? It is upsetting.

Comment: @henrytownshend Yes, but, if you want to measure impact, you need to establish first the algebra of issues. What are issues? Are they outstanding issue numbers as in $issues_{current}=issues_{old}-issues_{new}$? Do issues cluster by reclassification and lumping, as in $diagnosis=\sum issues$. I am not being difficult here. The meaning of the extracted information of any analysis is contingent upon the matter of definition of the parameters analyzed.

Comment: @AntoniParellada Let's give Henry a chance to mull it over. Even more disconcerting is the level of knowledge of statistics that my otherwise very knowledgeable medical colleagues usually have. It is very important to be patient to increase that level of understanding, especially in North America. In France, for example, you cannot get thru medical school with out calculus training, at least as last I heard.

Comment: @AntoniParellada If you want to be horrified consider this. For the last 100 years, the pharmaceutical industry and medicine have been using mixture distributions of polyexponentials as models. This is unrealistic. More realistic would be the following [paper](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0158798). For 200 hundred years, metabolism in medicine has been thought related to body surface area, and the correlation is spurious shown [here](http://www.academia.edu/download/46248177/An_improved_method_for_determining_renal20160605-7534-p6qhzc.pdf). Patience.